# Joining aggregate query onto different period ranges

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm working with invoice data to figure out rebate amounts that can be received. Some of them require a certain spend threshold to be eligible for the rebate so I need validation in place for that. Most of them have standard period ranges like years or quarters so I can join an aggregated spend amount onto the transactional level to calculate the rebate amounts, as my example query below shows.

```
SELECT
    FacilityName,
    Department,
    Item,
    InvoiceDate,
    InvoiceSpend,
    CASE WHEN YearSpend.TotalSpend > 1000000 THEN InvoiceSpend * 0.05
         ELSE InvoiceSpend * 0
    END AS RebateAmount
FROM Transactions
INNER JOIN 
            (
              SELECT 
                    YEAR(InvoiceDate) as [Year],
                    SUM(InvoiceSpend) as TotalSpend
              FROM Transactions
              GROUP BY YEAR(InvoiceDate)
            ) YearSpend ON YearSpend.Year = YEAR(Transactions.InvoiceDate)
```

For some of them though, they have periods such as November - April which cross different years, and quarters.

How would I go about joining the spend level validation for ones with this kind of period? Is there a way I could join on a period range like that?

Comment: Please provide some sample data that can be used as a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you compare `InvoiceDate` to other dates, e.g. `... @Q1Start <= InvoiceDate and InvoiceDate < @Q2Start ...`, you'll avoid various annoyances. The start and end may be in different years, but that isn't a problem. Note that the comparisons are different (`<=` and `<`) so that you can capture all of the invoices up to, but not overlapping, the next quarter/half/year. It also allows for the possibility of indexes improving performance.